# ADF CopyData Is it possible to have a dynamic mapping that can be nullable?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a configuration table with tables names to copy data. Sometimes I want all the columns, so I don't have to specify the mapping. But sometimes, I only want some columns. Is it possible to have a mapping json null and CopyDAta activity will take all the columns?

[image: ConfigurationTable]

I tried to have the value nullable like that:
[image]

But it throw an error when the value is null in the configurable table.

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a default mapping if null in the table.  From one of my Copy data activities with no mapping, it looks like

```
{
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "typeConversion": true,
    "typeConversionSettings": {
        "allowDataTruncation": true,
        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
    }
}
```

In the Mapping it would look something like this (not verified), replace the value in <> with above or better yet store in a variable and use the variable there.

```
@json(if(equals(item()?TrustedMapping, null), <default>, item()?.TrustedMapping))
```

Comment: ,Actually I am  stuck in one  scenario like this.Here my source is a xml .Here I want to check whether any column have 'null' value/'NAN'.I n both cases I need to replace with null in my traget sql database.If not replaced error will show since my target databse is configured to accept only double value for all columns.I got one solution.In my source dataset there is field called Null Value ,It will set blank in target for any value we input.I can use this for a 'null' condition in any case.But if both 'null' and 'nan' comes i cannot handle both at the same time.Can u help me on this case